# Should __main__.py reference another class/file to begin work?

Tags: python, conventions

I mostly program in Java and C++ so packages/execution in Python is a little new.

I have a medium-sized project for which I can call `python myproject` to run **main**.py within the `myproject` directory. I was wondering if it is appropriate or accepted to instantiate the project's main process within that **main**.py file or to have it call myproject.py to begin the work/create an instance of a `myproject` class to have it handle work.

I would be handing over command line arguments from **main**.py to the `myproject` class to enable some feature like debugging output/